# Java keytool error on keystore directory

Tags: java, android, keytool

All I'm trying to do is create a .keystore file for my android application.
But I have two problems

1. Where is the output .keystore file after I run this command?

   `keytool -genkey -v -keystore shumi.keystore -alias shumi -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
2. With problem #1, I tried looking for documentation I could understand and answered questions here on stackoverflow. I learned that `-keystore` should be a path but I can't seem to find the right syntax. I tried the following code but it gave me a `FileNotFoundException`.

   `keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:/shumi.keystore -alias shumi -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Happy Holidays and please, someone help.

Comment: keytool is annoying - much easier is [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) the open source GUI for working with keystores.

Comment: @Robert I agree that keytool is annoying, but you really shouldn't recommend Portecle anymore. Basically, Portecle is just a very old (2004) fork of [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org) and hasn't evolved much in those years. Since KeyStore Explorer became open source again in 2013, Portecle is obsolete now.

Comment: @Omikron I did not know about KSE, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Keytool generates the keystore file in the current folder, if you only pass a file name after `-keystore`.

The `FileNotFoundException` in your second command is just a permission problem: Windows doesn't allow regular users to create new files in `C:\`. Just use a path where you have write privileges like your home folder.